# Any screen management software for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**

I've got a monitor on my desk, and a TV on a unit right next to that desk.
The TV is connected to the PC as a secondary display, and I sometimes like to pull stuff over from the primary display to the secondary display.
Moving stuff over, e.g. a browser window with YouTube running, and then double-clicking it to make it full-screen, is quite an awkward process, since the TV is at an angle that makes it hard to look at when sitting by the desk.

So basically, anything that can't be done by memorizing and using keyboard shortcuts, such as e.g. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>/<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>, becomes pretty annoying.

**Here's my question:**

Is there any software for Windows 7 that let's me view and interact with my secondary display, from my primary display, e.g. in a window?

An obvious solution would of course be to just mirror the displays, but their resolutions don't match and thus one of the displays will look stretched out. :-/

I also, just now, tried to use Chrome Remote Desktop to remote into my own computer, and thus view both displays inside the browser, which is displayed on the primary display. This is close to what I'm looking for, except it doesn't work. The view of the first display inside the remote desktop application will recursively render, both my monitors, and none of the displays inside the application will respond to input, (to busy rendering itself into infinity i guess :-P).

I'm also aware that I could use wireless input methods so I don't need to sit in front of the desk, but that's not the problem, and also, Windows is not easy to navigate on a TV from a distance. :-P

Comment: Suggestions for a more informative title are totally welcome. ^_^

Comment: VNC into yourself =)

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: @Taegost Windows 7, will update post now to reflect that. :-)

Comment: Have you tried using 'Win'+'Right/Left Arrow' to move it over to the screen, then using 'Win'+'Up Arrow' to maximize it?  That should accomplish what you want in at most 3 button presses.

Comment: @Taegost As partly stated, partly implied, I already know those keyboard shortcuts. However, I do not know any for making a YouTube video go full-screen, and also I might sometimes want more control than what is provided through keyboard shortcuts. :-)

Comment: How about use a wireless mouse from where you can see both monitors?

Comment: @TTT I've already addressed that in the last paragraph of the question. :-)

Comment: @Phazyck - I thought that's what you meant, just wanted to clarify :)

Comment: @TTT - Ok. I purposely wrote it ambiguously, since using a smartphone or other wireless device as a peripheral would produce the same result. :-)

Comment: @Phazyck: this should work for Youtube: Win+Right Arrow (twice), F. To get out of full screen, Esc.